# How to Query database table in WSO2

Tags: wso2

I would like to know if it is possible to have a database query return a claim. We need to do a lookup on someone's username and return another value not in LDAP. Can this be accomplished in WSO2?

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific by mentioning which WSO2 product you are using? Anyway as a general there is a WSO2 product called [WSO2 DSS (Data services server)](http://wso2.com/products/data-services-server/) which is meant to communicate with databases. One way is doing this is connecting database to WSO2 DSS and connect that WSO2 DSS instance with WSO2 product you are using. Another way is you can select WSO2 DSS components which are used to communicate with database and install those components in your WSO2 specific product you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. To clarify, this is regarding Identity Server. The claim can even come from a secondary LDAP (one not used for authentication; although, the database method would be preferred. I need an attribute to pass to a service provider. I will take a look at DSS to see if this is a possibility.